# Angularfire firestore keeps giving insufficient permissions when trying to save to db

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

When i try to upload to cloud firestore, i keep getting the "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions"

these are my rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == request.auth.uid
      allow write:  if request.auth.uid == request.auth.uid
    }
  }
}
```

this is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../Models/Users';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(
    private auth : AngularFireAuth,
    private firestore : AngularFirestore,
    private altCtrl : AlertController
  ) { }



  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.auth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
  }
  async login(email:string, password:string):Promise<any>{
    var result = await this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    //var result = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
    if(result.user !== undefined ){
      var uid = result.user.uid;
      return uid;
    }else{
      return null;
    }
  }

  async createAccount(email:string,password:string, user:User):Promise<boolean>{
    try {
      var result = await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
      //var result = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
      if(result.user != undefined){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }


  async createUserDocument(user:User):Promise<boolean>{
    try {
      await this.login(user.email, user.password);
      var result = await this.isLoggedIn();
      if(result){
        await this.firestore.collection('Users').doc(user.first_name).set(user);
        //await firebase.firestore().collection("Users").add(user);
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }


    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
      return false;
    }
  }


}
```

this is my app module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { LoaderComponent } from './widgets/loader/loader.component';
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import { AuthGuard } from './Guards/auth.guard';
import { AutoLoginGuard } from './Guards/auto-login.guard';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import {  AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { FirebaseService } from '../app/Services/firebase.service';

//real information hidden for security
const config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoaderComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy
    },
    AuthGuard,
    AutoLoginGuard,
    SQLite,
    SplashScreen,

    FirebaseService,

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

the save to the database only works if the rules are set to if true.

In my cause, users are allowed to modify data as long as they have been authenticated

Comment: Anyone have an answer??

Comment: if request.auth.uid == request.auth.uid always resolves to true - so that is interesting. If you check on if request.auth.uid == null and if request.auth.uid != null what happens? Likely, if things work while users are authenticated but request.auth.id == null, then you might consider changing the firebase version to 8.3.0 as mentioned as a response.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! ill give it a try !

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is from Angular 12 or from firebase.
I solved it by downgrading firebase to version 8.3.0

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2857

Comment: Awesome, im new to downgrading packages, whats the command to downgrade the firebase version?

Comment: I not the best to answer that but in your project package.json setting the version to "^8.3.0" and runnning ``npm install`` in the project directory should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Well i found some kind of a solution. But i can't really explain why it works.

Solution:
First i add `private afAuth: AngularFireAuth` to the constructor of a random component. It still dosn't work after that.
But if i add `this.afAuth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);` or `this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());` anywhere (even if those lines get never called) inside that random Component the AuthService suddenly works and spits out all the data i want.

Details:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2864

Comment: Honestly seems like a valid answer to me, this package has some really weird bugs in it... ill give it a try! thanks!